# C: Insert symbols to be displayed after the input cursor

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am getting the annual interest rate from the user. I want '%' to be displayed while the user is entering the interest rate. Here's what it should look like:

```
Enter the annual interest rate: %
```

Notice the hanging '%'. The cursor should be blinking right before (or on, whichever) the '%' so that when the user types, say, 2.9, it looks like this:

```
Enter the annual interest rate: 2.9%
```

Then, the user presses ENTER and the code continues as normal on a new line.

Is this even possible in C? And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as a console program. You can do it with some GUI. You can always prompt like "Enter the annual interest rate (%): " to remind the user though.

Comment: It is possible on console using _clrscr() and _getch(), but it is not very practical.

Comment: @Armin I don't think this is going to work on platforms different from Windows.

Comment: This is not possible with the standard C I/O library. It was designed to work well with electric typewriters and punched tape, not them newfangled CRT things. You need a terminal I/O library such as GNU Readline (native for Unix but I think there is a Windows version too).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the program in a command line terminal,  you can use gets() call.
Note a double % is required in printf to output one % sign.

```
 double percentRate;
 printf("Enter the annual interest rate: %%");
 char input[256];
 gets(input);
 // then parse the input buffer
 percentRate = atof(input);
```